# Removing char hex codes from string

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, character-encoding

I have a folder named `Folderć`, which contains smth.jpg. As folder has letter `ć` in name, filepath is saved in database as `Folder%C0%01%/smth.jpg`.
Letter `ć` is saved as Hex code. This is not a problem while previewing image on website.

Problem happens when i am trying to make a subfolder in `Folderć` via C# function. Function gets filepath string, finds folder name and creates subfolder in it. As my string contains hex code instead of letter `ć` function cant find that path thus cant create subfolder.

That string is in UTF-8 format, so changing the encoding doesnt change anything.
Anyone knows where is problem and how to solve it?

Comment: "filepath is saved in database as Folder%C0%01%/smth.jpg" Is that what you see when you run a select in SQL Server management studio?

Comment: What type do you use for the column in your DB?  You should be able to use nvarchar to allow for Unicode characters and then not need to do that type of encoding.

Comment: My mistake, file path is saved normally with letter ć, and column is nvarchar. It comes with that hex symbols after a sql query.

Comment: This looks like a UrlEncoding. How are you reading that value from the db? What route does that value take before you try to create that folder?

Comment: This is correct. Using HttpUtility.UrlEncode Method saved a day. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can encode the name with Base64:

```
public string ToBase64String(string text)
{
    byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(data);
}
```

and use it `string myEncFolderPath = ToBase64String(myFolderPath);` before saving the string in the DB.

After you receive the string from the DB, you can decode it back to a normal string with:

```
public string FromBase64String(string base64)
{
    byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
}
```

by using `string myFolderPath = FromBase64String(myEncFolderPath);`.

That way, you can save strings freely in the DB.

Comment: When the column is `nvarchar`, you shouldn't need to do this. And it apparently did save correctly.